# need help with '... read more' excerpt in functions.php

Tags: functions, excerpt, read-more

I have this to generate the link:

```
<a class="view-article" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __('View Article', 'html5blank') . '</a>';
```

But I don't want it to open the post page. I want it to pop open my modal like this:

```
<href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class=""> view article</a>
```

I broke WP once and would like not to do it again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I broke WP once and would like not to do it again."_ ... to give you some confidence: When writing a single plugin, I break WP 5 times per hour - on purpose. The question just is: Where do I break it? For me it's just my local sandbox. For you it's probably your life site. Do you see the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Breaking a site is a good thing, as long as you know what site you break. PROTip: Get a local setup.

Comment: Fixed it. But I will get a local setup going. Thanks. Best idea I've had all day. ;)

Comment: If you fixed it, then please provide the solution as answer. Answering your own question is something that we all like here on this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a couple of blind tries, but I got it.

**Before:**

```
<a class="view-article" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __('View Article', 'html5blank') . '</a>';
```

**After:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-' . $post->ID . ' " class="over">' . __('View Article', 'html5blank') . '</a>'
```